# How to limit SonataMediaBundle gallery to a single provider?

Tags: php, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-3.3, sonata-media-bundle

An existing project on which I am working uses SonataMediaBundle. I like the Gallery option provided by that bundle, with one caveat: The gallery allows users to include not just images, but also media from three video providers (YouTube, Vimeo and DailyMotion).

**How can I make the bundle only allow images as gallery media?**

So far, I have tried searching GalleryAdmin.php for any reference to provider names, but I have yet to find anything obvious in there.

Edit: I also realize that I could just remove the providers I don't want from the `sonata.yaml` file (and/or `sonata_media.yml` depending on setup), but that would entirely remove them from the application, which is not quite what I want. I still want to be able to use the YouTube provider, for instance -- just not when creating image galleries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, I came up with a workaround that isn't perfect but does the job. I added the following block to sonata_media.yml:

```
galleries:
    providers:
        - sonata.media.provider.image

    formats:
        abstract: { width: 100, quality: 100 }
        wide:     { width: 820, quality: 100 }
```

... which is not ideal, since it adds a step to the workflow. (I now have to tell clients "If you want to make a gallery, choose the 'galleries' context and then do xyz." It's a bit cluttered, but it reduces the likelihood of unpredictable results.)

Comment: Another option is to change the default context. But that could change existing workflows, which I don't want.

Comment: Why don't you accept your own answer? If it solves your problem, then it's good for accepting/upvoting (the later you can't do, but I can - and did it).